# How can I get the ControllerContext in the class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'd like to gain access to the ControllerContext in the class library. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what information you want to get from there. It may be available in other places. For example controller name and action can be retrieved from

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Comment: Returns null for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is is possible?

No, this is not something that I would recommend you doing. Don't tie your class library to any ASP.NET specific things such as a controller context. Pass whatever information this library needs as arguments.

There are other ways to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve than retrieving a ControllerContext from a class library.

Comment: "Don't tie your class library to any ASP.NET specific things such as a controller context" -Why not?

Comment: @Administrateur, because then the code in this class library cannot be reused in other types of applications.

Comment: While that's a generally a good idea, if I'm writing a control library for a specific app, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov What if the library is specific to MVC and renders Razor View to string? how can we get controller content there ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You would have to reference the System.Web.Mvc assembly in the class library and then pass the ControllerContext object to the method you are calling.

The question on whether it is recommended depends on what you are doing. Generally it is not recommended to pass MVC base objects to another assembly dealing with Models.